Free struct with 2d array
I am pretty new to C and I have this problem:
I am defining a struct with a 2D Array and its rows and columns
// Structure to represent a 2D array of integers with the given dimensions
typedef struct {
    int **data;
    int rows;    
    int cols;
} Array2D;

// Creates a 2D array with the given dimensions and initial value
Array2D *create2DArray(int rows, int cols, int initialValue) {
    Array2D *array = malloc(sizeof(Array2D));
    array->rows = rows;
    array->cols = cols;

    array->data = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array->data[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            array->data[i][j] = initialValue;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

I also wrote a function that should free the struct but it does not seem to work:
void freeArray2D(Array2D *array) {
    int **data = array->data;
    for (int i = 0; i < array->rows; i++) {
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);
    free(array);
}

When running this test code, I am watching the memory usage of that script, but it does not get less after 10s:
int main(){
Array2D *testGrid = create2DArray(1300, 1300, 0);
sleep(20);
freeArray2D(testGrid);
sleep(5);
return 0;
}

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Memory is not necessarily freed immediately upon calling free it depends on the implementation and also on the OS. BTW what OS do you have and how do you watch the memory usage? probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305899/free-not-freeing-up-memory-properly

@Jabberwocky Thaks for your answer, I am on macOS and used top to view cpu and memory usage. Maybe the "true" memory usage is smaller than what top shows me

Try malloc_stats() if it is supported.

@WeijunZhou I will try that later, thanks for the suggestion

freeing may not be done by the OS for some time for a used memory location.
You did not mention how you checked the usage.
However, you might be able to check the virtual memory in Linux with the following.
grep "VmRSS\|VmHWM" /proc/`ps -u ${USER} | grep <your-program> | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | cut -d " " -f1`/status

And GCC 11.4, it does show me less memory after free with your code.

Thaks for your answer, I am on macOS and used top to view cpu and memory usage. Interesting that it works for you, maybe the "true" memory usage is smaller than what top shows me

@Goldenfaeron: the process probably has the memory still allocated, but when (if) another allocation is needed after calling freeArray2D(), the released memory will be reused if the freed memory is big enough.  The memory is available for reuse.

@JonathanLeffler Thanks for answering, unfortunately this is not the case for me. I use this in a recursive search algorithm and after just a few seconds the code is taking up gigabytes of memory.

@Goldenfaeron Please edit your question and show a [mre] that is taking up lots of memory. Maybe your real code has special behavior that does not allow re-using freed memory or there might be some other memory leak.
